# Electron app opening all pages upon startup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, electron

I am setting up a multi-paged electron application, however whenever I start my application it opens all the pages, and anytime I click a button that is supposed to bring the user to the next page, it skips ahead and opens the other pages as well.

I believed the issue was with setting the parent/child relation of each window, however when commenting or removing those properties the issue persists.

```
const{app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron');
import{fstat} from 'fs';
import{resolve} from 'path';

const packagejson = require('../package.json')

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('touch-events', 'enabled'); 

if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { 
  app.quit();
}

let mainWindow;
let startWindow;
let setOriginsWindow;

const createWindow = () => {
  startWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
  });

  startWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);

  startWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  startWindow.on('closed', () => {
    startWindow = null;
  });
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);

ipcMain.on('set-origins', (event) => {
  setOriginsWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  })
  setOriginsWindow.on('close', function() {setOriginsWindow = null});
  setOriginsWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/set_origin_page.html`)
  setOriginsWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    setOriginsWindow.show();
  });
  setOriginsWindow.openDevTools();
  if(packagejson.ENV == "dev"){
    setOriginsWindow.openDevTools();
  }
})
    // parent:startWindow,
    // fullscreen: true,
    // modal:true,
    // show:false

ipcMain.on('start-procedure', (event) => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  })
  mainWindow.on('close', function () {mainWindow = null});
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/main_page.html`);
  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.show();
  });
  mainWindow.openDevTools();
  if(packagejson.ENV == "dev"){
    mainWindow.openDevTools();
  }
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (startWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
'''
```

The 1st page to open should be a splashscreen with button that when pressed, will open page 2. Page 2 has a button that when pressed will open page 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron is not good for multipage apps, and displays a blank screen for around a quarter of a second when changing pages. Instead, you might want to create a file with all pages combined and switch between them with DOM methods

For Example

```
var splash_screen = document.getElementById('splash-screen');
var second_screen = document.getElementById('second-screen');
var third_screen = document.getElementById('third-screen');
document.removeChild(second_screen)
document.removeChild(third_screen)
var splash_button_click = () => {
document.removeChild(splash_screen);
document.appendChild(second_screen);
}
```